# Cursors in MySQL - do they create temporary table or not

Tags: mysql, cursor

I'd like to discover how MySql cursors actually works.
I have a MySQL 5.6 server and want to run complex stored procedure, that updates rows in one table and makes inserts in another.
My problem is misunderstanding how cursors in MySQL actually works.

1. In official reference docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html) cursors are called "Asensitive: The server may or **may not make a copy of its result table**", which means, that cursors don't create any temporary copy of data if you don't declare cursor with `FOR UPDATE` and works as pointer to actual data.
2. In http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ cursors also described as "Asensitive:  cursor performs faster than an insensitive cursor because **it does not have to make a temporary copy of data**. However, **any change that made to the data from other connections will affect the data that is being used by an asensitive cursor**, therefore, it is safer if you do not update the data that is being used by an asensitive cursor. MySQL cursor is asensitive."

But in dev docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/cursor-restrictions.html) i can see

3. "In MySQL, a server-side **cursor is materialized into an internal temporary table**. Initially, this is a MEMORY table, but is converted to a MyISAM table when its size exceeds the minimum value of the max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size system variables. The same restrictions apply to internal temporary tables created to hold the result set for a cursor as for other uses of internal temporary tables. "
   which means, that cursors on OPEN query creates temporary table with snapshot of data and any changes to table will not affect cursor data.

Can you tell me, how cursors in MySQL actually works? I'd like to create cursor on big table in my stored procedure and don't want to create copy of data.

Comment: Knowing how cursors 'work' isn't going to be much use to you since you don't have any control over it. In general cursors are to be avoided and usually can be. You might want to state what you are trying to do and someone may be able to suggest an alternative to cursors.